# Problems in items in the ViewPager inside another ViewPager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I am creating a movie app. Currently, I am showing all movie items in a `RecyclerView` within a `Fragment`. When a user clicks on a specific movie item, the `ListFragment` is replaced by the `DetailsFragment`. I can swipe to next item from `DetailsFragment`, so I used a `ViewPager` there. In `DetailsFragment` I have an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. The `ImageView` contains the image of the movie. I am using `Glide` to load the image. As a movie item can contain multiple images of the movie. I have used another `ViewPager` to swap between the images. I have done all of this without any problem. However, the problem begins when I wanted to resize the movie image with their original aspect ratio. The images are not resizing the way they should. When swiping in the nested `ViewPager`, Images are often being resized either with the dimension of next item or previous item.

Whenever the user clicks on an item in `ListFragment`, I populate the First `ViewPager` with all movie items from the `Activity` and setCurrent item to the clicked item. Then, I take all the images of that movie in an array, fetch their `bitmap`, calculate new width and height according to the device size and resize the `bitmap`. Then, I send those images to the nested `ViewPager`. But, let's say I have three images for a movie and the second image is being resized with the aspect ratio of the first or third Image.

In the 'MainActivity', I am creating some movie items and attach the `ListFragment`:

```
movieList = mutableListOf()

        val movie = setMovie(
            "1",
            "Fight Club",
            "A movie worth watching",
            "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjJmYTNkNmItYjYyZC00MGUxLWJhNWMtZDY4Nzc1MDAwMzU5XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,676,1000_AL_.jpg",
            "https://www.rollingstone.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/rs-19014-fightclub-1800-1406035542.jpg?crop=900:600&width=1440",
            "https://cdn-static.denofgeek.com/sites/denofgeek/files/styles/main_wide/public/2017/02/fight-club_main.jpg?itok=rdIIiUuT"
        )

        val movie1 = setMovie(
            "2",
            "The Shawshank Redemption",
            "A movie worth watching",
            "https://files.kstatecollegian.com/2015/06/c4728ae2-cf07-4ae6-af7e-34cf3cb38dbe-696x1044.jpg",
            "https://i0.wp.com/www.moviehousememories.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/The-Shawshank-Redemption-2.jpg?w=1278&ssl=1",
            "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51b3dc8ee4b051b96ceb10de/t/5b3e33e270a6ad4a13a68537/1530803174357/?format=1500w"
        )

        val movie2 = setMovie(
            "3",
            "Titanic",
            "A movie worth watching",
            "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg4MzQxMjIyNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTA3NTk1Nw@@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,1380,1000_AL_.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/RMS_Titanic_3.jpg/800px-RMS_Titanic_3.jpg",
            "https://imgix.bustle.com/uploads/image/2017/6/23/23e8ab61-7603-4bf3-bbed-00818829afd1-titanic.png?w=970&h=546&fit=crop&crop=faces&auto=format&q=70"
        )

        movieList.add(movie)
        movieList.add(movie1)
        movieList.add(movie2)

        val fragment = FirstFragment()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).commit()
```

The model class of `Movie`:

```
    var id: String? = ""
    var name: String? = ""
    var desc: String? = ""
    var image1: String? = ""
    var image2: String? = ""
    var image3: String? = ""
```

The `ListFragment` aka `FirstFragment`:
`

```
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    adapter = CustomAdapter(activity!!, (activity as MainActivity).movieList)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

`

The Adapter of `FirstFragment` aka `ListFragment`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        p0.textView.text = movieList[p1].name

        p0.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val fragment = SecondFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("pos", p1)
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            val transaction = (activity as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
            transaction.commit()
        }
    }
```

Now, the `SecondFragment` which holds the first `ViewPager`:

```
val adapter = ItemAdapter(childFragmentManager, (activity as MainActivity).movieList)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        val bundle = arguments
        if (bundle != null) {
            position = bundle.getInt("pos")
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true)
        }
```

Now, the adapter of the First `ViewPager`:

```
class ItemAdapter(
    fm: FragmentManager?,
    val movieList: MutableList<Movie>
) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Fragment {
        val fragment = ThirdFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable("movie", movieList[p0])
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return movieList.size
    }
}
```

Now, the `DetailsFragment` aka `ThirdFragment` (This contains the nested `ViewPager`):

```
images = mutableListOf()
        allItems = mutableListOf()

        val bundle = arguments
        if (bundle != null) {
            val movie = bundle.getParcelable("movie") as Movie

            images.add(movie.image1!!)
            images.add(movie.image2!!)
            images.add(movie.image3!!)

            for (i in 0 until images.size) {
                val fetchData = FetchData()
                fetchData.asyncResponse = this
                fetchData.execute(images[i])
            }

            tvName.text = movie.name
        }

        adapter = AnotherAdapter(childFragmentManager, allItems)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        return view
    }

    override fun processFinish(imageProperty: ImageProperty) {
        val width = imageProperty.bitmap!!.width
        val height = imageProperty.bitmap!!.height
        val originalRatio: Double = width.toDouble() / height.toDouble()

        val deviceWidth = viewPager.measuredWidth
        val scaledHeight = deviceWidth.toDouble() / originalRatio

        imageProperty.width = deviceWidth
        imageProperty.height = scaledHeight.toInt()

        Methods().showLog("Link: ${imageProperty.link!!}")
        Methods().showLog("Width: ${imageProperty.width}")
        Methods().showLog("Height: ${imageProperty.height}")

        allItems.add(imageProperty)
        adapter = AnotherAdapter(childFragmentManager, allItems)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
    }

    class FetchData : AsyncTask<String, Void, ImageProperty>() {
        var asyncResponse: ImageResponse? = null
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): ImageProperty {
            return try {
                val url = URL(params[0])

                val connection = url
                    .openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                connection.doInput = true
                connection.connect()
                val input = connection.inputStream
                val imageProperty = ImageProperty()
                imageProperty.link = params[0]
                imageProperty.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
                imageProperty
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                val imageProperty = ImageProperty()
                imageProperty.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(null)
                imageProperty
            }
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: ImageProperty?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            asyncResponse?.processFinish(result!!)
        }
    }
```

The model class of `ImageProperty`:

```
class ImageProperty() : Parcelable {
    var link: String? = ""
    var width: Int = 0
    var height: Int = 0
    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
```

The Adapter For Nested `ViewPager`:

```
class AnotherAdapter(fm: FragmentManager?, private val list: MutableList<ImageProperty>) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Fragment {
        val fragment = FourthFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable("image", list[p0])
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
}
```

And, Finally, the last fragment for displaying the image (Currently I am not using `ImageView` but `TextView` to check whether my Image is being correctly resized. They are being correctly resized. But If you check the `ViewPager`, it is not being resized with the dimension in the `TextView` rather they are being resized either with the next item or previous one):

```
val bundle = arguments
        val imageProperty = bundle!!.getParcelable("image") as ImageProperty

        val textView2 = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)
        val textView3 = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView3)
        val textView4 = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView4)

        textView2.text = imageProperty.link
        textView3.text = imageProperty.width.toString()
        textView4.text = imageProperty.height.toString()

        (parentFragment as ThirdFragment).viewPager.layoutParams.width = imageProperty.width
        (parentFragment as ThirdFragment).viewPager.layoutParams.height = imageProperty.height
        (parentFragment as ThirdFragment).viewPager.requestLayout()
```